# readFileSync is returning empty string

Tags: javascript

Reading a file using `readFileSync` is returning an **empty string**.

I am reading contents of a file using link which is retrieved from the database. It is working.

But I am unable to read the file using link which is stored in a variable.

My code is given below:

```
var result1={};

var filename="/home/rgukt/Project 2.0/CCMS/Admin/Challenges/"+(req.body.challenge_name)+"/"+(req.user.username)+"_expected_output"+(result[i].test_case_id)+".txt"  ;

result1.output = fs.readFileSync(result[i].output,'utf8'); // working

result1.expected_output = fs.readFileSync(filename,'utf8'); // not working
```

Comment: What's the value of `result[i].output`? Have you compared it with value in `filename`?

Comment: result[i].output consists of path to a file

Comment: That's obvious. I meant to compare the values, to see what's wrong with path in `filename`. You show us some path based on 3 unknown variables and ask what's wrong with it. Show results of `console.log(filename)` and `console.log(result[1].output)`

Comment: it is a part of compiling a code submitted by user.The code shown above is placed in a loop. result[] is contains the test cases path i.e result[0] contains path to the 1st testcase file and result[1] contains path to the 2nd testcase file of a problem statement. filename is varied in each time and it contains the path to the user output of respective testcase which is stored previously.

Comment: For example if result[0] is /home/rgukt/Project 2.0/CCMS/Admin/Challenges/Find Sum/output1.txt then filename would be  /home/rgukt/Project 2.0/CCMS/Admin/Challenges/Find Sum/R141330_expected_output1.txt. Here R141330 is username and Find Sum is challenge name and "1" in "expected_output1" is testcase id.